# How to connect to PostgreSQL from Azure Function App written in Java?

Tags: java, postgresql, azure, jdbc, azure-functions

I've an Azure function app which has a timer trigger function written in Java. I need to connect to PostgreSQL which is deployed on one of the Azure VMs(not using Managed Postgres here).

My code :

```
import java.sql.*;

public class MyFunction {

    public static final String DB_URL              = "jdbc:postgresql://<host>:<port>/<dbName>";
    public static final String DB_USER             = "<dbUser>";
    public static final String DB_PASSWORD         = "<dbPassword>";

    @FunctionName("timerTrigger")
    public void timerTrigger(@TimerTrigger(name = "timerTriggerFunc", schedule = "0 */30 * * * *")
                                         String timerInfo, ExecutionContext context) {

        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
    }
}
```

When I run this function, its throwing the following exception :

```
[11/29/2019 10:42:24] java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://<host>:<port>/<dbName>
[11/29/2019 10:42:24]   at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
[11/29/2019 10:42:24]   at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
```

Please help resolving this. I went through other questions in stack overflow and browsed, but didn't get my use case elsewhere.

Comment: You apparently don't have the Postgres JDBC driver in your classpath

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That, or the driver isn't on the initial classpath but on a context classpath and needs to be loaded explicitly.

Comment: @StanleyGong I'm not the person that asked the question.

Comment: Hi @mypeople , has your issue been solved ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to import the postgresql driver. I use the code below to connect to my database successfully:

```
import java.util.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.*;
import java.sql.*;
/**
 * Azure Functions with HTTP Trigger.
 */
public class Function {

    @FunctionName("HttpTrigger-Java")
    public HttpResponseMessage run(
            @HttpTrigger(name = "req", methods = {HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST}) HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,
            final ExecutionContext context) throws ClassNotFoundException {

        Connection c = null;

        try {
           Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
           c = DriverManager
                   .getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://<DB server>:5432/<dbname>",
                           "<username>", "<password>");
        } catch (SQLException e) {

           return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK).body(e.getMessage()).build();
        }


       return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK).body("Opened database successfully").build();

    }
}
```

Adding latest postgresql Driver in maven `dependencies`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
  <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
  <version>42.2.8.jre7</version>
</dependency>
```

Result on Azure Java function:

[image]

Comment: Hi, is it helpful for you ?